# CiviCRM theme not loading after URL change

Tags: drupal, urls, resource-urls, shoreditch

I've changed the URL of our site from beta.example.net to example.net and now CiviCRM is loading with the Drupal frontend theme instead of it's own.

I've enforced the change by updating the line in .htaccess that's enforcing https. It now reads as

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've also updated the base URL in Drupal's settings.php to

```
 $base_url = 'https://example.net';
```

and the site URL in civicrm.settings.php with

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://example.net/');
}
```

I've also tried setting the CMS root in civicrm.settings.php with both

```
define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR', 'https://example.net/');
```

and

```
define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR', '/var/sites/c/example/public_html/');
```

but neither seems to make any difference.

My best guess was that I'd broken something with Shoreditch, trying at some point in the past to define a relative URL so that CiviCRM wouldn't constantly display an error. But I've gone to https://example.net/civicrm/admin/extensions (I can't navigate to it through the current theme) and disabled Shoreditch and the error is still occurring.

With Shoreditch enabled, this is how the resource URLs screen currently looks:
[image: Screenshot of Resource URLs screen]

Screenshot of the current state of the extensions page:
[image: Extensions page, showing Shoreditch is enabled]

And, just to confirm I cleared the cache:
[image: CiviCRM reporting cache cleared]

Drupal's own backend loads as expected (though somewhat slowly). Drupal 7.67. CiviCRM 5.18.2. Shoreditch 0.1-alpha34.

Comment: Does a clear cache helps? Go in your browser to https://your-site/civicrm/clearcache?reset=1 also shoreditch has checkbox under Administer --> System settings --> resource url

Comment: Cache clear doesn't help. No sign of the Shoreditch checkbox - I've just added a screenshot above.

Comment: There should be a radio button next to custom css. Are you sure shoreditch is enabled?

Comment: Well it's definitely _reporting_ that it's enabled. Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1):

I updated CiviCRM, and all seems fine now!